# Get GHCi input and output history of the current session

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Is there a way to get everything that was typed by the user and outputed by GHCi in the current session?

I'm talking either from within the session itself, or externally from the process.

I also need to know which lines are input and which are output.

Comment: [This](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghc-flag--interactive-print) can get you the output without to much work. Alternately, `script` (called from a shell) could do the job (but might be a bit verbose).

Comment: Yeah, that hook is great. It might just work. Shame there isn't a similar one for input.